# LWC Pass RecordId to Parent of Parent

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm trying very hard to build out something similar to the [bike card example](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics) from Salesforce.

I have a tile, list, and selector component in a hierarchy, and then another component Registration that should function similar to the details component in the trailhead.

The problem is that I can't get the data to populate like I expect. Here is what I think is happening:

1. List.cmp is getting the records from the database correctly
2. List.cmp is then iterating through the list, creating a separate tile.cmp for each
3. Tile.cmp is populating correctly with the data
4. Tile.cmp is creating a button
5. Tile.cmp is triggering a custom event and passing the selected Id up the hierarchy
6. List.cmp gets the data correctly and sends up another custom event with the given Id
7. Selector.cmp gets the event correctly
8. Selector.cmp ? tries to put the value into `selectedEventRegistrationId`
9. Selector.cmp then creates Registration.cmp and passes the received `selectedEventRegistrationId` as `giveneventid`
10. Registration.cmp performs an @wire getRecord on the `giveneventid`
11. Registration.cmp should be able to show specific info on the record
12. From here I can build what I need

The issue as I see it happens at step 8. I can't really verify that the id is being passed as I want it. As you can see, I have included a lot of debug logs. Here is what I am seeing in the debug log:

- Button was clicked
- List received the event, will try to send to selector
- uoeventid =
- a1R3F000001hQT7UAM
- The selector has received the event
- selectedEventRegistrationId =
- `TypeError: this.uoEvent.data is undefined`

I get the Registration.cmp to display the `This should show before selecting a tile` bit and then disappear when I click a button. So I think that means it is getting SOMETHING, right? Then I struggle with getting what I assume is the id into the Registration.cmp and that pulling the data from SF correctly.

Could someone review and tell me what I am doing wrong? Or perhaps that I have it all wrong and where / how to start over?

I guess my two biggest questions are:

1. Am I passing the id all the way up to Selector and then to Registration like I think I am?
2. Why won't Registration get/display the record I want?

I tried to cut out parts of the code that are working so that the overall post isn't as long.

---

**tile.html**

```
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="Register" title="Primary action" onclick={handleRegister} icon-name="utility:retail_execution" icon-position="left" class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

**tile.js**

```
export default class OutreachEventTile extends LightningElement {
    @api uoevent;
    
    handleRegister(){
        console.log("Button was clicked");
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('registerevent', {
            detail: this.uoevent.Id
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }
}
```

**List.js**

```
handleTileRegistration(event){
    console.log("List received the event, will try to send to selector");
    const uoeventid = event.detail;
    console.log('uoeventid = ');
    console.log(uoeventid);

    //Fire another event that gives the Event ID to the Selector component
    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selectevent', {
        detail: uoeventid,
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}
```

**Selector.html**

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">Register</header>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="columns">
        <main class="main" >
            <c-outreach-event-list onselectevent={handleEventRegistrationClick}></c-outreach-event-list>
        </main>
        <aside class="sidebar-second">
            <template if:true={selectedEventRegistrationId}>
                <c-outreach-event-registration giveneventid={selectedEventRegistrationId}></c-outreach-event-registration>
            </template>
            <template if:false={selectedEventRegistrationId}>
                This should show before selecting a tile
                <br/>
                {selectedEventRegistrationId}
            </template>
        </aside>
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Selector.js**

```
import { LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class OutreachSelector extends LightningElement {
    selectedEventRegistrationId;

    handleEventRegistrationClick(event){
        console.log("The selector has received the event");
        this.selectedEventRegistrationId = event.detail;
        console.log('selectedEventRegistrationId = ');
        console.log(selectedEventRegistrationId);
    }
}
```

**Registration.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title={cardTitle} icon-name="standard:event">
        <div class = "slds-m-vertical_medium slds-m-left_medium">
            <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">
                <lightning-formatted-date-time value={startDateTime} year="numeric" month="short" day="2-digit" weekday="long" 
                    hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" time-zone-name="short">
                </lightning-formatted-date-time>
            </h1>

            <br/>

            <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Event Description</h1>
            <p>
                <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={publicDescription} ></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
            </p>

            <br/>

            <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Event Location</h1>
            <lightning-formatted-address
                street={streetAddress}
                city={cityAddress}
                province={stateAddress}
                postal-code={zipAddress}
            ></lightning-formatted-address>
        </div>
        
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Registration.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


const fields  = [
    'UO_Event__c.Name',
    'UO_Event__c.Title__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Public_Title__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Account__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Point_of_Contact__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Activity_Type__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Audience_Type__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Street_Address__c',
    'UO_Event__c.City__c',
    'UO_Event__c.State__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Zip_Code__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Start_Date__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Start_DateTime__c',
    'UO_Event__c.End_Date__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Military_Branch__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Military_Status__c',
    'UO_Event__c.Public_Description__c',
    'UO_Event__c.OwnerId'
];

export default class OutreachEventRegistration extends LightningElement {
    @api giveneventid;

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$giveneventid', fields })
    uoEvent;

    get cardTitle(){
        return this.uoEvent.data.fields.Public_Title__c.value;
    }

    get streetAddress(){
        return this.uoEvent.data.fields.Street_Address__c.value;
    }

    get cityAddress(){
        return this.uoEvent.data.fields.City__c.value;
    }

    get stateAddress(){
        return this.uoEvent.data.fields.State__c.value;
    }

    get zipAddress(){
        return this.uoEvent.data.fields.Zip_Code__c.value;
    }

    get startDate(){
        return this.uoEvent.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value;
    }

    get startDateTime(){
        return this.uoEvent.data.fields.Start_DateTime__c.value;
    }

    get endDate(){
        return this.uoEvent.data.fields.End_Date__c.value;
    }

    get publicDescription(){
        return this.uoEvent.data.fields.Public_Description__c.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to change the event to follow the example from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)

`new CustomEvent('selectevent', {
        detail: {
           uoeventid: uoeventid
        }
});`

Then instead of `this.selectedEventRegistrationId = event.detail;` to do `this.selectedEventRegistrationId = event.detail.uoeventid;`? Do you get the Id value on step 8 after this change?

Comment: I am not getting an exception per se. I am not able to set `selectedEventRegistrationId` in the Selector (which is the parent of all). From there, I want to pass that ID to the sibling child component Registration, and that should be the variable `giveneventid`

Comment: I tried the change you suggested for the detail{} on `List.js` but I get the same issue. `selectedEventRegistrationId =` [nothing gets returned the next line] and then: `TypeError: this.uoEvent.data is undefined`

Comment: Okay can you try this `const uoeventid = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail));` instead of `const uoeventid = event.detail;`?

Comment: I tried that too, @arthlete and it still does not return a value for the `selectedEventRegistrationId `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial load is going to have this error because you don't check if data is populated yet. Use getFieldValue instead:

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

...

```
get publicDescription(){
    return getFieldValue(this.uoEvent.data,'UO_Event__c.Public_Description__c');
}
```

Also, you should be using field tokens instead of plain strings for your fields.

Everything else looks fine, from what I can tell.

---

Edit:

Field tokens are used to compile-time validate that the field exists:

```
import UOEVENT_PUBLIC_DESCRIPTION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/UO_Event__c.Public_Description__c';
```

Which you can then use in your fields:

const fields  = [
UOEVENT_PUBLIC_DESCRIPTION_FIELD, ...

And in the getter method:

```
get publicDescription(){
    return getFieldValue(this.uoEvent.data, UOEVENT_PUBLIC_DESCRIPTION_FIELD);
}
```

...

Comment: Thank you. Now my card will render, but it doesn't receive the data from the button like I expect. `selectedEventRegistrationId ` still shows nothing (I guess undefined?). A couple of follow up questions, if you don't mind. What do you mean by field tokens? And can you explain the difference between the return statements so I understand and dont make the same mistake in the future please? Thank you again.

Comment: @Chance added a bit about field tokens. The difference in return types is that getFieldValue checks for null values and so doesn't throw the error; your code presumes that the object is already fully populated, which is not the case before the wire method returns data.

Comment: Would that be why the card is not populating? Do you think it actually is getting the id from the button?

Comment: @Chance Also, since you're using the getRecord API, I think the following line is wrong: `detail: this.uoevent.Id` it should be `detail: this.uoevent.fields.Id.value`.

Comment: @sfdcfox How come that when he console.logs the `uoeventid` he gets a value if the value is not there yet?

Comment: @Arthlete It's available from the source, but not from the component loading the record details.

Comment: @sfdcfox I finally understood what you meant. The wire has not completed when the getter runs so it displays the `type error`. I thought you were talking about the `console.log(selectedEventRegistrationId);`. Thank you.

Comment: OK, so it took me forever to figure it out and understand what you were talking about and I still had issues. Then I found out that FLS was still not set for the community this was going on, and causing the result to break. Always check FLS. Thank you both.  @Arthlete